# Remove all event listeners in a function via function reference

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a function that is implicitly called in another function: for example I have a function like:

```
function a() {
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
  // some stuff...
});
}
```

and I am executing this function when a specific view loaded  via its reference like:

```
function x() {
  // loaded view...
  // other stuff...
  a.apply(null, [parameters]);
}
x();
```

when the view is destroyed, I want to unbind all event listeners and others.

What is the best way to do this over this function's reference?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be is to extract eventLisnter function into separate function let's call it `abc()`

```js
const abc = function(event) {
// some stuff...
}
```

then you could do

`window.addEventListener("hashchange", abc);`

and if you would like to remove (unsubscribe) it down the road,
you could just call the following:

`window.removeEventListener("hashchange", abc);`

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener